# Python code after a call to f2py wrapped function does not execute

Tags: python, fortran, f2py

I'm trying to use some existing code for integrating delay differential equations in a python project (radar5 from [this page](http://www.unige.ch/~hairer/software.html) ). I thought I had successfully wrapped the fortran code with f2py because I was able to call a fortran program and see output from the integrator.

But, all python code after the call to radar5 does not execute.

The python code:

```
import numpy
import radar5_f2pytest
print(radar5_f2pytest.__doc__)
i=[2]
x=[0]
rpar=numpy.array([1.34, 1.6E9, 8.0E3, 4.0E7, 1, 1, 6E-2, 6E-2, 15E-2],order='F')
ND=2
NRDENS=1
NGRID=1
NLAGS=1
NJACL=2
MXST=4000
LWORK=11
LIWORK=16
IJAC=1
MLJAC=ND
IMAS=0
IOUT=1
X=0
Y=numpy.array([1E-10,1E-5],order='F')
TAU=rpar[8]
XEND=100.5
ITOL=0
RTOL=1E-9
ATOL=RTOL*1E-9
H=1E-6
IWORK=numpy.zeros((16), order='F', dtype=numpy.int64)

WORK=numpy.array([1E-16, 0.9, 0.001, min(0.03, RTOL**0.5), 1, 1.2, XEND-X, 0.2, 8, 0, 5], order='F')
IWORK[1]=1000000
IWORK[4]=ND
IWORK[2]=7
IWORK[8]=1
IWORK[10]=2
IWORK[11]=MXST
IWORK[12]=NGRID
IWORK[13]=1
IWORK[14]=NRDENS
IPAST=numpy.zeros((NRDENS+1), order='F')
IPAST[0]=2

GRID=numpy.array([TAU], order='F')

ipar=numpy.zeros((1))
#print((WORK))
#print(IWORK)
print("WHAT")
radar5_f2pytest.radar5_f2py(X, Y, XEND, H, 
                                  RTOL, ATOL, ITOL, IJAC, 
                                  MLJAC, NLAGS, NJACL,
                                  IMAS,ND,0, IOUT, WORK, 
                                  IWORK,GRID, IPAST, rpar, ipar)


print("WHAT")
```

The fortran code. Note that there are external dependencies, and other subroutines, but for brevity, I will only include the subroutine that I am wrapping with f2py.

```
! -*- f90 -*-

SUBROUTINE radar5_f2py(N, X, Y, XEND, H, RTOL, ATOL, ITOL,& 
&                          IJAC, MLJAC, MUJAC, NLAGS, NJACL, &
&                          IMAS, MLMAS, MUMAS, IOUT, WORK, IWORK, &
&                          GRID, IPAST, RPAR, IPAR, IDID, RESULT)
   
    IMPLICIT NONE
              
    INTEGER, PARAMETER :: DP=kind(1D0) 
    INTEGER, intent(in) :: N, NLAGS, NJACL
    REAL(kind=8), intent(inout) :: X
    REAL(kind=8), intent(in) :: XEND
    REAL(kind=8), intent(in) :: H
    LOGICAL, intent(in) :: ITOL, IJAC, IMAS, IOUT
    INTEGER, intent(in) :: MLJAC, MLMAS, MUMAS

    INTEGER, intent(in) :: MUJAC
    !f2py integer, optional, intent(in) :: MUJAC


    REAL(kind=8), dimension(N), intent(inout) :: Y 
    REAL(kind=8), intent(in), dimension(11) :: WORK 
    REAL(kind=8), intent(in) ::  ATOL,RTOL 
    INTEGER, intent(in), dimension(16) :: IWORK 
    REAL(kind=8), intent(inout) :: GRID 
    INTEGER, intent(inout) :: IPAST 
    REAL(kind=8), intent(in), dimension(9) :: RPAR 
    INTEGER, intent(in) :: IPAR
    INTEGER, intent(out) :: IDID
    REAL*8, intent(out), dimension(1,N) :: RESULT
    REAL(kind=8), EXTERNAL :: PHI
    REAL(kind=8), EXTERNAL :: ARGLAG
    EXTERNAL :: FCN, JFCN, JACLAG, SOLOUT, DUMMY

   !PRINT *, X, Y, WORK, ATOL, RTOL, IWORK, GRID, IPAST, RPAR, IPAR     
    CALL RADAR5(N,FCN,PHI,ARGLAG,X,Y,XEND,H,&
     &                  RTOL,ATOL,ITOL, &
     &                  JFCN,IJAC,MLJAC,MUJAC, &
     &                  JACLAG,NLAGS,NJACL, &
     &                  IMAS,SOLOUT,IOUT, &
     &                  WORK,IWORK,RPAR,IPAR,IDID,&
     &                  GRID,IPAST,DUMMY,MLMAS,MUMAS,RESULT)
    

    
     RESULT(1,1)=1
     !PRINT *, X, IDID
     RETURN   

END SUBROUTINE
```

The f2py module was compiled with this command:

```
 flang -c radar5.f contr5.f dc_decdel.f decsol.f dontr5.f 
================================================================
start f2py...
f2py -c -m radar5_f2pytest radar5_template.f90 radar5.o contr5.o dc_decdel.o decsol.o dontr5.o only: radar5_f2py :
```

I first compile the fortran source files and then feed them to f2py with a source file containing the subroutine above.

To reiterate, I can see output from fortran indicating that the call to RADAR5 is working. And the results match examples given by the authors of radar5.

I have tried debugging the python code, but that merely confirmed that nothing after the second call to the f2py module executed.

EDIT:

Sorry for the delay and the lack of a reproducible example. I have been trying to make an example that shows this issue without breaking something else, but radar5 is quite large and complicated, and I am inexperienced with fortran. The issue is related to the call to radar5, since if I do not call radar5 at all, everything works as expected. In the meantime, here is the output:

```
This module 'radar5_f2pytest' is auto-generated with f2py (version:1.21.5).
Functions:
  idid,result = radar5_f2py(x,y,xend,h,rtol,atol,itol,ijac,mljac,nlags,njacl,imas,mlmas,mumas,iout,work,iwork,grid,ipast,rpar,ipar,n=len(y),mujac=)
.
WHAT
 STARTING INTEGRATION...
 NUMBER OF PRESCRIBED GRID POINTS:             1
 NUMBER OF DELAYED COMPONENTS:             1
 INTEGRATION...
            0  COMPUTED BREAKING POINTS:
```

Here, I know that radar5 is being called and is executing because of the last line. I can also print out results (from fortran) like IDID or the final point of the integration. These results have been as expected.

EDIT 2:

Running the python code in an interactive window causes a crash:

Version details:

```
Python 3.9.13 (main, Aug 25 2022, 23:51:50) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.31.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.
```

Output in interactive window:

```
Canceled future for execute_request message before replies were done
The Kernel crashed while executing code in the the current cell or a previous cell. Please review the code in the cell(s) to identify a possible cause of the failure. Click here for more info. View Jupyter log for further details.
```

Comment: Welcome, I suggest taking the [tour]. Please show also the output of your code. What exactly is printed?

Comment: Also, youu should show the code of `RADAR5` or create a smaller case and still exhibit the problem - se [mcve]. Note that the link you gave does not work.

Comment: You really should show us more than just an updated link. We should not need to download a full external package to reproduce your problem. Try to call a small dummy version of that subroutine. If the problem persists, show us that dummy version as a full [mcve]. If not, the problem will be connected with the subroutine internals and you will have to show us that subroutine directly, not in a link. That is really necessary.

Comment: But foremost, you really have to show **the output** you are presently getting. *"I can see output from fortran indicating that the call to RADAR5 is working"* What exactly are you seeing? After what exact command?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Sorry about the partial edit that did not include the output. I've updated the post with the output as requested.

Comment: What happens if you try to execute the `radar5_f2py` function in an interactive python or ipython shell (REPL)?

Comment: If something bad happens inside that complicated Fortran code than I am afraid there is no other way than doing the hard work and debugging the Fortran code. Yes, it can take a long time and it can take a lot of time. The usual techniques apply: try using a debugger, try inserting some debugging print statements,... But sometimes there is simply no simple solution at hand. Double check the correctness of all types of your arguments when calling `RADAR5` inside `radar5_f2py`. Or triple check.

Comment: I've added that output to the question. Also, thanks for your help.

Comment: BTW, you are declaring your arguments as `real(8)` while RADAR 5 is declaring them as `kind(DP)` where `DP=kind(1D0) `. While it is probable OK to work in practice, it is not safe. You should follow all argument types exactly.

Comment: Try calling `radar5_f2py` from Fortran and try using normal Fortran debugging techniques. Compiler checks, all warnings enabled, address sanitizations, valgrind and so on. Examine any backtraces you get. It is very likely a crash inside the Fortran code. Most probably some incorrect way of calling the subroutine.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out the error.

This answer was relevant: [segfault on f2py callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36753722/segfault-on-f2py-callback). Specifically, examining the c code that f2py generates with --build-dir and --debug-capi allowed me to find where things were breaking exactly.

The issue seems to have been with the specification of the variable GRID. I originally did not specify a dimension for GRID in the wrapped subroutine, so it seems that f2py assumed it was a scalar. GRID is inout, so it's modified by the radar5 call. Radar5 runs fine, but when results are returned, the mismatch between the modified grid (now an array) and the expectation of f2py causes a segmentation fault.

Correctly specifying GRID as an array seems to fix everything.